# How to update validationSchema dynamically when using hooks

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Similar to issue [1436](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1436) but I am using the react hook `useFormik`. I would like to set `validationSchema` after fetching a JSON schema in an API call and use [schema-to-yup](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/schema-to-yup) to create the Yup validation function.

So I currently do this:

```
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {},
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(vals, null, 2));
        }
```

Later I try to do this:

```
formik.validationSchema = buildYup(data);
```

This results in no validation being performed, if I create a valid test Yup schema when `useFormik` is initialized it does validate but I need to do it later for my application.

- Am I using `useFormik` wrong?
- is there a better pattern here?
- would this only be possible if a `setValidationSchema` function was exposed?

Comment: You can pass a `validate` function instead of a schema. The function can even be async, so fetching the JSON schema first should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As an example for the answer of @super:

```
const generateValidation = () => {
 const obj = {};
 if(condition) obj[key] = yup.string().required();
 return yup.object().shape(obj);
}

...
validationSchema: generateValidation()
```